# How to remove context menu from a button generated as MVC ActionLink inside of a Kendo.Grid() column

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-grid, contextmenu, html.actionlink

When generating `Kendo.Grid()`, the column is generated as follows:

```
<td role="gridcell"><a class="modal-link k-button k-primary total" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="showLoader" data-ajax-complete="showLoaderPopup" data-ajax-failure="CheckError" href="/Controller/Method?Id=001&amp;Amt=9.5&amp;desc=4.+Text1+Text2+Text3+vs+F+Fs+-+M+P" style="width: 80px;">4</a></td>
```

When generating `ClientTemplate` I added `someFunction()` function and when calling it, I do the following:

How can I disable context menu for that button?

```
function someFunction(){
    $('.total').contextmenu(function () {
        return false;
    });
}
```

However, context menu is still showing.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about registering the context menu open event with a function?

```
function contextMenuOpen(e) {
    if ($(e.target).containsClass("total")) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This is a pseudo code that I havent´t tested but it should work if you are using kendo context menu withing the kendo grid (theoretiacally).

However, if I am misunderstanding the question then you could clarify and I could perhaps update my answer.  Hope this helps  :)